# При выборе из Core data try не заходит в секцию catch

Tags: swift, coredata

Доброго времени суток!
Есть код:

```
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    var result: [Entity2]? = []
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exportLockIdQ != nil")  //Такого поля нет
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: String(describing: Entity2.self))

    request.predicate = predicate

    do {
        try result = context.fetch(request) as? [Entity2]// fetch(request) as! [T]
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
        //throw CoreDataError.FetchError(error: error)
    }
```

Поля **exportLockIdQ** нет в классе Entity2.
fetch обернут в try, но при вызове в секцию catch не заходит, а вываливается sigabrt и приложуха закрывается.
Объясните плизь в чем прикол.

Comment: И так тоже. Проблема в том, что в секцию catch даже не заходит. Немного не привычно видеть такое после c#.

Comment: И лучше вместо var result: [Entity2]? = [] записать как var result = [Entity2](). Будет просто пустой массив.

Answer (score 1):

А ошибки и не будет. Запрос вполне корректный, просто ни один из объектов не подходит под ваш фильтр. Чтобы проверить "ошибку", которую вы хотите получить, лучше проверяйте количество результатов запроса свойством массива .isEmpty